Helping to see if I well understood default constructor, copy constructor and operator=
so I have this piece of code in C++:
T create (size_t n);
bool condition_one(T t);
bool condition_two(const T &t);
void modify(T &t);

T generate(size_t n){
T a(1);                     //line 0
T b = create(n);            //line 1

while (!condition_one(b)) { //line 2
  modify(b);                //line 3
  if (condition_two(b)) {.  //line 4
     break;                 
  }
}
return b;                   //line 5 
}                           

I have a memory management question which asks what among the three members; default constructor, copy constructor and operator=, should be synthesized in type T for line 1 to 5 ?
It is explicitly said as well that line 0 requires none of those three.
I am a little bit lost with those three. So far this is my proposal :
line 1 should take a copy constructor as we initialize a data using already existing data.
line 2 should go with a copy constructor because I think that we initialize the loop variable using already initialized data as well
line 3 I would say default constructor because there is no initialized data from a void function
line 4 I'd say default constructor for the same reason
line 5 I have no clue tbh. I'd say none of them if I have to shoot because this is a return so it does not need to be initialized
You see from what I am saying, I am confused. I just wanna understand those concepts of memory managing to see and answer my question precisely.
Thanks for your help

Why note make your own class T that implements the various constructors and operators to print out a message when they are called?  Then you can run the above program and see for youself exactly what is getting called and when.

The answers for some of your cases depend on which C++ standard you are building for (or your compiler supports).  Before C++17, an implementation (i.e. compiler) was permitted but not required to elide [i.e. not create] temporaries if the only way of monitoring their lifetime was to track constructor and/or destructor calls.    Since C++17, elision of temporaries is mandatory in a number of situations.

Best website for learning C++

For C++17 using clang++ with -O2, I got line 0: none. 1: none. 2: copy ctor. 3: none. 4: none.  5: none.   (Could vary depending on the implementations of the declared functions, and the unknown class T.)

Line 1
T b = create(n);

It receives a size named n and creates a T object of the given size. You do not have an original T object to copy the second from, hence create will instantiate T, likely with a constructor or a default constructor and the result is assigned to b.
Line 2
!condition_one(b)
Since b is passed by value, at the time the function is called a copy constructor is being called to copy the object. Since it's passed by value, the function will operate on the value and changes upon this value will not affect the original object that was copied.
Line 3
modify(b);

No constructor is needed. Since b is passed by reference, you are essentially passing the address of the object, so if changes are applied inside the function upon the object, then b will be changed as well accordingly. No constructor here. The declaration of
void modify(T &t);

essentially says that I do want to modify t, so I expect to receive t, not a copy of t, so I can successfully change it.
Line 4
condition_two(b)

There is no constructor involved here, as the declaration of
bool condition_two(const T &t);

compels the caller to pass t by reference. By contrast, bool condition_one(T t); specified t as an object that is to be passed by value, this is why a copy constructor was in use at Line 2.
Line 5
return b;                   //line 5 

A new object is created from the local object via a copy constructor and then the local object is destroyed.
